# Error: Can't select within an unnamed vector

Tags: r

I have a dataset named "cog_gpa" in R subsetted from the fragile families data set that contains student GPA and some test scores used to measure cognitive abilities. I want to run a random forest to check which ones are more important than others in terms of predicting the GPA.

My dataset (cog_gpa) is a tibble (4898*5) and looks somewhat like this:

```
ch5dsss  ch5ppvts  ch5wj9ss  ch5wj10ss  GPA
13.0000  98        104.0000  117.0000   3.7500
9.0000   76        84.0000   84.0000    3.5000
9.3524   92        92.6763   97.9623    4.0250
```

When I check `str(cog_gpa)`, I see that all the predictor variables are of the type "dbl+lbl" whereas GPA is of type "num".

I start with the following where I split by GPA:

```r
cog_gpa_split <- initial_split(cog_gpa$GPA, prop = .7)
```

However, I get the following error:

```r
Error: Can't select within an unnamed vector.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

When I run `rlang::last_error()`, I get the following:

```r
<error/rlang_error>
Can't select within an unnamed vector.
Backtrace:
 1. rsample::initial_split(cog_gpa$GPA, prop = 0.7)
 2. rsample::mc_cv(...)
 3. tidyselect::vars_select(names(data), !!enquo(strata))
 4. tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

When I run `rlang::last_trace()`, I get the following:

```r
<error/rlang_error>
Can't select within an unnamed vector.
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-rsample::initial_split(cog_gpa$GPA, prop = 0.7)
 2.   \-rsample::mc_cv(...)
 3.     \-tidyselect::vars_select(names(data), !!enquo(strata))
 4.       \-tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
```

How do I go about resolving this error? I think I need to ensure that all of my variables are of the same type (i.e. all of them should be of the type numeric) but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What exactly is your goal when you say you want to "split by GPA"?

Comment: You need to split the data, not a column. It should look more like `initial_split(cog_gpa, prop = .7)`. Are you trying to do a stratified split? Maybe `initial_split(cog_gpa, prop = .7, strata=GPA)`?

Comment: Thanks! I want to predict GPA based on other variables using decision trees. My outcome (GPA) is continuous. Should I still use "strata=GPA" if I am trying to predict an outcome that is continuous?

Comment: @Tannya Kumar, please consider providing us with a minimal reproducible example so that we can best help you.

Comment: I figured this out. Thanks :)

Comment: @MrFlick, what is a stratified split? How is initial_split(cog_gpa, prop = .7, strata=GPA) different from initial_split(cog_gpa, prop = .7) ?